# FreeImage Loading image into OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, freeimage

[image]Previously, I have been loading bitmaps (.bmp) using a loader into an OpenGL texture using a tutorial bmp loader, but I want to be able to load different textures, so trying FreeImage.

I am trying remove gamma correction, but with FreeImage the image isn't displayed correctly.

Previously I was using :

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0, 
             TextureFormatForBitmapFormat(bmp.PixelFormat(), true),
             (GLsizei)bmp.Width(), 
             (GLsizei)bmp.Height(),
             0, 
             TextureFormatForBitmapFormat(bmp.PixelFormat(), false), 
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
             bmp.PixelBuffer());
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

GLenum OpenGLTexture::TextureFormatForBitmapFormat(Bitmap::Format format
    , bool srgb)
{
    switch (format)
    {
       case Bitmap::Format_Grayscale: return GL_LUMINANCE;
       case Bitmap::Format_GrayscaleAlpha: return GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA;
       case Bitmap::Format_RGB: return (srgb ? GL_SRGB : GL_RGB);
       case Bitmap::Format_RGBA: return (srgb ? GL_SRGB_ALPHA : GL_RGBA);
       default: throw std::runtime_error("Unrecognised Bitmap::Format");
    }
}
```

Using FreeImage, the code:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, (GLsizei)width, 
             (GLsizei)height, 0, GL_BGRA,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)FreeImage_GetBits(img));
```

The problem is that using FreeImage, I am getting a really 'flat' light from it.  Is there a way to effectively reproduce what I have previously done in FreeImage?

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: What does "flat" light mean? Please add an image.

Comment: @BDL Sorry, you are right, I have added an image.